# Goto Definition in Emacs - Haskell mode

Tags: haskell, emacs

I installed `Haskell Mode` through Melpa `package-install`. However, `M - .` (`goto-definition)` still uses emacs' inbuilt findTags function. Doesn't haskell mode has this goto function definition feature?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`haskell-mode-jump-to-def` isn't bound by default, [but you can bind it yourself](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-mode/wiki/Haskell-Interactive-Mode-Tags):

> ### Using GHCi
>
> You can bind the following to use GHCi to find definitions of things:
>
> ```
> (define-key haskell-mode-map (kbd "M-.") 'haskell-mode-jump-to-def)
> ```
>
> The one problem with this approach is that if your code doesn't compile, GHCi doesn't give any location info. So you need to make sure your code compiles and the modules you want to jump to are loaded byte-compiled.

Alternatively, you can use a tags file or GHCi / tags hybrid approach as suggested later on that same page.

Comment: Chris, goto definiton works well when i generate `TAGS` file using hasktags inside project directory. However, for lib files sitting in user package as ~/.cabal/libs, it doesn't work. So, how to configure user/global package when using `haskell-mode-jump-to-def`?

Comment: @MadhavanKumar, sorry, I don't know.

Comment: What's the best way to reverse this and jump back to where you came from?

Comment: Looks like I had to go with `M-*`, which calls `pop-tag-mark`. I use `M-,` in `clojure-mode`, but it wasn't working here for some reason.